# B* tree Data Structure Insertion

Tags: tree

Evening.I am trying to understand the concept behind B*-Tress.I do understand B-trees and B+ -trees, but I have a problem with B*trees.My question is, If I have a tree of order five for instance.Now I am given an empty tree to start insertion(1,2,3,4,5).But when five is entered,the node(being the root) is full.Some splitting needs to be done.How do I do that.Can I split it like how I would in a B-Tree.If i do, I voilate the rule of being 2/3 full.Or is there another rule for splitting the root?Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Everyone, is this a stupid question or is everyone else clueless as I am.My code works but dont know what to do if the root is full.